# Is it okay to copy and paste in your answers?

Tags: discussion

[This comment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/why-is-the-israeli-palestinian-conflict-such-a-big-issue/63592#comment256713_63592) by a [fairly high rep user](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/21531/italian-philosophers-4-monica) says that

> this has substantial content cut and pasted from a previous answer of yours. I hope you don't plan on spamming this site with repeat cut and pastes

(This question is only about that piece of the comment, not the other parts of it). I have 2 questions

1. Why is copy-pasting a negative thing to do?
2. What should be done when you want to use something you’ve already used, or should you not re-use stuff?

Edit: this also applies to copy-pasting parts of answers.

Comment: Also note that the same user's old answer [in question] was deleted. (The old answer claimed that Palestinians have no right whatsoever to be in Israel. I haven't checked their new answer.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There should usually not be a need to post duplicate content on this website.

When you find two different questions which indeed have the same answer, then these two questions are [duplicates](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates). Instead of copy&pasting an answer you already posted on a different question, mark the question as a duplicate of that question.

When the question isn't a duplicate, then you should modify your answer so it better fits the different scope of the new question. Alternatively, if you believe that what you wrote somewhere else is relevant to the question even though it is not a full answer, you can always reference your previous answers by linking to them. Example:

> Q: Can the president of Arstotzka fire the minister of defense because he was caught urinating in public?

> A: As I wrote in [this answer about firing the minister of agriculture for jaywalking](https://example.com), the president of Arstotzka can fire any minister for gross misconduct. However, according to Article 1345b (3) of the Constitution of Arstotzka, public urination is specifically exempt.

Comment: What about copy-pasting part(s) of a previous answer?

Comment: @EkadhSingh In that case you might want to consider to link to your other answer. Answer updated.

Comment: I up-voted this specifically because of the reference to Arstotzka.

Answer (score -1):

it is per policy usually not OK to "repost again". and in most cases it indicate that the question can be a duplicate.

Although, if the answer was deleted *only* because the question it was posted on was deleted, it's ok to post to again in a similar question that fits it.

And if you think that in the case the question is not a duplicate, its just a more specific question that only needs part of that other answer you can add there and cite(with link) the more complete answer in the other topic in case the asker or any visitor wants more details.

Comment: Please clear up a possible misunderstanding (either yours and/or downvoters here): it is per policy usually *not OK* to "repost again" if that answer itself was deleted specifically (for whatever reasons stated). It is another matter for example if an answer is deleted because the question was deleted and simply dragged down an answer that was otherwise OK.

Comment: @LаngLаngС ok i edited. thank you for explain what's the problem ,and specially for me being a beginner here and when people just start to downvote i can only see the minus points and wonder what?! why ?!

Comment: When you say the other post do you mean the other answer or the question it was posted on?

Comment: @JoeW to  the other answer. When the person clicks it will open the question already scrolled in the answer  position. In that way, who arrives just for that part gets the fast answer without needing to read and filter the whole answer(like a tl:dr) and the ones who want more clarification can follow the link and see if the complete version have the details or even find in the other answers of that similar/related question.

Comment: Not sure how that applies to something being deleted.